# Autodesk Forge Authentication - "The client_id specified does not have access to the api product"

Tags: authentication

Trying to follow tutorials but cannot get past authentication. From OSX shell:

curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate' -X 'POST' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d 'client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=MY_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=data:read'

I get back:
...
* Connection #0 to host developer.api.autodesk.com left intact
{ "developerMessage":"The client_id specified does not have access to the api product","userMessage":"","errorCode":"AUTH-001","more info":"http://developer.api.autodesk.com/documentation/v1/errors/AUTH-001"}

I have enabled all of the APIs in the app's configuration page.

I regenerated the secret key twice - same result.

If I had screwed up the client_id/secret key somehow, it looks like I would get an AUTH-003 error so I don't think that is the problem.

Documentation lists several possible errors but not AUTH-001.

Any ideas on how to debug this?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way to get past that was to delete that app and create a whole new one from scratch. The new ID/Secret works.